# Centos 8 davfs2 Error: Unable to find a match

Tags: linux, centos, davfs2

When trying to install davfs2 on Centos 8 using:

```
yum install davfs2
```

I get the message "Error: Unable to find a match". I have tried

```
sudo yum -y install epel-release
```

and tried installing with dnf instead of yum based on some searches I did. My problem is I'm not super well-versed with Unix and I can't find much on Centos 8 to help me out. Everything come back with Centos 7 when I try searching.

Is davfs2 not supported on Centos 8, or am I just going about this the wrong way? I have installed it on Centos 7 using this method before.

Comment: The EPEL 8 repository does not contain the `davfs2` package. It is still available on the EPEL 7 repository. The package information is [here](https://apps.fedoraproject.org/packages/davfs2). I guess you could reach out to the maintainer of the package for clarification. CentOS 8 is still pretty new, so it may simply be that the package has not been built for it yet.

Answer (score 1):

davfs2 is in EPEL now and should be installable.